# Drawing Curves with Grease Pencil

Tags: interface, add-on, bezier-curves, edit-mode, grease-pencil

Is there a way to draw perfect curves with grease pencil the same way i do with the bezer/path curve?

I know that you can smooth a GP drawing, but it would be good to do it the same way of the "poly" mode, where you draw straigth lines countinuosly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. The Poly Mode of Grease Pencil drawing is for drawing polygons only. Hence no subdivision (or smoothing) will happen on those grease pencil strokes.

Answer (score 0):

The grease pencil 'curve tool' gives a high degree of control over the line shape, but NB. these are not editable bezier curves. Here's a video demonstrating how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBpbtCQSGUA

[image]